# How can I find the correct MIME content type of a OPENDAP URL (NetCDF file)?

Tags: r, mime-types, netcdf

In an application I am trying to validate that a user specified URL leads to a NetCDF file (.nc). However, I've noticed that (some?) URLs generated by OPeNDAP return a content type of `text/html` instead of `application/x-netcdf`.

e.g. The URL below is to a NetCDF file, but in R, using the `httr` package I get:

```r
u <- "http://test.opendap.org/opendap/data/nc/test.nc?cr"
httr::headers(httr::HEAD(u))[["content-type"]]
#> [1] "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
```

In other cases the correct content type is returned:

```r
u <- "https://dapds00.nci.org.au/thredds/ncss/uc0/Test_pixel_count.nc"
httr::headers(httr::HEAD(u))[["content-type"]]
#> [1] "application/x-netcdf"
```

Is there any way to determine that the first URL is a NetCDF file?

Or if not, any practical suggestions on things to check that would give some confidence that the file is a likely a NetCDF file? Other than checking that the URL contains ".nc" (which isn't very robust) I can't think of any other ways to check this.

Comment: If I browse to that first URL, I see an error message that says "Unrecognized request". Is that really a valid netCDF file?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I've replaced the broken URL with a valid netCDF file which shows the issue.